# Ruby: Rspec double confusion

Tags: ruby, rspec

A failing test has me questioning my understanding of what a test double is (test framework is RSpec).

From my understanding:

> A mock is a fake object that stands in for a collaborator of the subject under test

So lets say that I have a `Person` class:

```
class Person 

  def default_number_of_products 
    Product.new 
  end

end
```

**and** a `Product` class:

```
class Product
  def initialize 
    @default_number = 3
  end
end
```

To test that calling `default_number_of_products` on Person results in Product receiving `new`, I write a test that looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe Person do 
  let(:person) { Person.new }

  describe '#default_number_of_products' do     
    it 'invokes new on product' do 
      product = double(Product)
      expect(product).to receive(:new)
      person.default_number_of_products
    end
  end
end
```

which fails and returns this error:

```
// ♥ rspec spec/lib/person_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) Person#default_number_of_products invokes new on product
     Failure/Error: expect(product).to receive(:new)

       (Double Product).new(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/lib/person_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01006 seconds (files took 0.1052 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/lib/person_spec.rb:21 # Person#default_number_of_products invokes new on product
```

On the other hand, the test below passes:

```
RSpec.describe Person do 
  let(:person) { Person.new }
  let(:product) { Product }

  describe '#default_number_of_products' do   
    it 'invokes new on product' do  
      expect(product).to receive(:new)
      person.default_number_of_products
    end
  end
end
```

**Question**:

- I thought that one could remove the dependency on a collaboration object by using a double - this way, tests can be written without having to implement the collaborating class. The results above point out that
  my understanding isn't quite right. What I am missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Here's how to mock that call to Person.new:

First, let's make the `Person` and `Product` classes a bit more realistic...

```
class Person 
  def default_number_of_products 
    Product.new.default_number
  end
end

class Product
  attr_reader :default_number

  def initialize
    @default_number = 3
  end
end
```

Now for the `Person` tests that mock the `Product` class...

```
describe Person do
  subject(:person) { described_class.new }

  describe '#default_number_of_products' do
    let(:product) { instance_double(Product, default_number: 42) }

    before do
      allow(Product).to receive(:new).and_return(product)
    end

    it 'returns 42' do
      expect(person.default_number_of_products).to eq(42)
    end
  end
end
```

Had the code in `Product` executed, the call to `person.default_number_of_products` would have returned `3`. Instead, this test spied on `Product.new` and returned a double in place of a real `Product`. So, when the code in `person.default_number_of_products` executes, it sees the double, which has a `default_number` of 42.

Finally, in your question above you mentioned that you thought that mocks should allow you to create one class without have to create the collaborators. That is a true statement. However, in the tests above, `instance_double(Product, ...)` actually creates a duck type from the real `Product` class. So, it would need to be defined. If you wanted to TDD this before creating the `Product` class, you could pass a string in place of the class name, like this:

```
let(:product) { instance_double('product', default_number: 42) }
```

HTH

Comment: I would like to ask some clarifying questions but its a bit too involved so I will open up another post; hopefully you will see that post and be able to help.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to keep your clarifying questions here on this thread so that others with the same questions can see the answers all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

double is just object you create to interact with your test, for acting like a 'class' you can use `class_double`. When you write `product = double(Product)`, it creates some test var `product` but doesn't replace the existing `Product` class.

from: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double

> class_double is provided as a complement to instance_double with the
>   difference that it verifies class methods on the given class rather
>   than instance methods.
>
> In addition, it also provides a convenience method as_stubbed_const to
>   replace concrete classes with the defined double

This will work:

```
it 'invokes new on product' do 
  product = class_double(Product).as_stubbed_const
  expect(product).to receive(:new)
  person.default_number_of_products
end
```